# Como apagar informação no BD usando DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

alguém sabe me informar qual comando devo colocar para apagar do Banco de dados usando a informação da celular selecionada?
Coloquei assim:

```
    SQLcmd.CommandText = ("DELETE FROM usuario WHERE nome = '" & DataGridView3.IsCurrentCellInEditMode & "' ")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas pelo visto não deu certo....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para pegar o valor do *dataGrid* seria apenas isso:

```
var valordacelular = DataGridView3.CurrentCell.Value;
```

Não é indicado você concatenar o valor direto na *string* do SQL não, abaixo como sua linha iria ficar, mas que não é aconselhável.

```
SQLcmd.CommandText = ("DELETE FROM usuario WHERE nome = '" & DataGridView3.CurrentCell.Value & "' ");
```

O correto seria você adicionar parâmetros dentro da *String* assim:

```
SQLcmd.CommandText = ("DELETE FROM usuario WHERE nome = @param1");
SQLcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SQLcmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param1", DataGridView3.CurrentCell.Value));
```

Comment: entendi, mas seu deixar como vc disse que minha linha iria ficar e não é aconselhavel, teria algum problema de execução?

Comment: Não teria problema de execução não.

Comment: eu deixei desta forma
        SQLcmd.CommandText = ("DELETE FROM usuario WHERE id = '" & DataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value & "' "

Comment: isso, no caso vc pega a linha selecionada e a celula zero dela, vai pegar o valor do id que você quer sim. Bom que te ajudou, se atendeu sua dúvida não deixa de marcar  resposta.

Comment: obrigado, ajudo sim :)